# Find how many times "Index" appers in array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out if "Index" exist in my array, and second then count how many time it does appear.

Nothing of what I'm trying is working, this is the best attempt i've made, but cant turn my head around this.

```js
var arr = {"__metadata":{"id":"a5e55ca2-c574-434e-8ec3-1b9cd4595bcb","uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)","etag":"\"2\"","type":"SP.Data.SalesListItem"},"FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/FirstUniqueAncestorSecurableObject"}},"RoleAssignments":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/RoleAssignments"}},"Activities":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/Activities"}},"AttachmentFiles":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/AttachmentFiles"}},"ContentType":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/ContentType"}},"GetDlpPolicyTip":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/GetDlpPolicyTip"}},"FieldValuesAsHtml":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsHtml"}},"FieldValuesAsText":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/FieldValuesAsText"}},"FieldValuesForEdit":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/FieldValuesForEdit"}},"File":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/File"}},"Folder":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/Folder"}},"ParentList":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/ParentList"}},"Properties":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://lavanet.sharepoint.com/sites/devcla/_api/Web/Lists(guid'cc4de542-1c06-4f53-b787-b8a2d42fe21e')/Items(1)/Properties"}},"FileSystemObjectType":0,"Id":1,"ServerRedirectedEmbedUri":null,"ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl":"","ContentTypeId":"0x010048CF0CAB992F7B409B79C034586FFB7E","Title":"Test data 1","Date":"2017-01-01T08:00:00Z","Index":20,"Index2":15,"ID":1,"Modified":"2017-04-18T12:27:19Z","Created":"2017-02-03T10:02:10Z","AuthorId":17,"EditorId":17,"OData__UIVersionString":"1.0","Attachments":false,"GUID":"d87fa9d2-c81e-4dfd-b568-c8a300fc12d8"}



function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var x;
    for (x in list) {
        if (list.hasOwnProperty(x) && list[x] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

console.log(containsObject("index", arr));
```

Would love if someone could help a bit

Comment: First of all, your "array" is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) ;)  
  
Second you want to know how often "Index" is inside your Object -> on which level -> do you want to check your Object deeper than just one level or only on top level should it be exactly "Index" or also "Index2"?

Comment: `list[x] === obj` will only be true if key and value are the same (`"index": "index"`)

Comment: Using **hasOwnProperty** to test for a property's existence..
Using **list[x] === obj** to check for is there "index" key and "index" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to count both if key and/or value of prop === index and not bother of case-sensitivity, then you can try something like this.

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
  var cnt = 0;
  for (var x in list) {
    var val = list.hasOwnProperty(x) && list[x] ? list[x].toString() : '';

    if (x.toLowerCase() === obj.toLowerCase() ||
      val.toLowerCase() === obj.toLowerCase()) {
      cnt++;
    }
  }
  return cnt;
}
```